# error="invalid_grant", error_description="Bad credentials" in Spring oauth2

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to integrate Spring security oauth to a struts application.I am getting the above error which I am not able to resolve.I am restricting to access to /oauth/token by Spring Security.

ApplicationCOntext.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<beans default-autowire="byName">
    <!-- 
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="m2m"/>
        </bean>
    -->


    <bean id="currencyRateService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/CurrencyRateService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="reportService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/ReportService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="invoiceService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/InvoiceService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="entercarduserService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/EnterCardUserService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="userService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/UserService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="userLoginStatusService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/UserLoginStatusService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <!--  <bean id="campaignService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/CampaignService/remote" />
    </bean> -->
    <bean id="rewardService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/RewardService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="partnerService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/PartnerService/remote" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="socialService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/SocialService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="activityService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/ActivityService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="constantService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/ConstantService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="regionService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/RegionService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="verificationService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName"
            value="m2m/VerificationService/remote" />
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="trophyService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/TrophyService/remote" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contentService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/ContentService/remote" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/TemplateService/remote" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="partnerUISettingService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName"  value="m2m/PartnerUISettingService/remote" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/M2MDS" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Cache -->
    <!-- <bean id="cacheManager" class="net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager" factory-method="getInstance" />  -->
    <bean id="cacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionCache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
        <property name="cacheName" value="m2msession" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="applicationCache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
        <property name="cacheName" value="m2mapplication" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contextCache"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.web.cache.EhcacheContextCache">
        <property name="sessionCache" ref="sessionCache" />
        <property name="applicationCache" ref="applicationCache" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Utils -->
    <bean id="contactImporter"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.contact.OZContactImporter" />

    <bean id="helperUtils"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.web.util.HelperUtils">
        <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
        <property name="constantService" ref="constantService" />
        <property name="rewardService" ref="rewardService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pecuniosusManager"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.service.PecuniosusManager"
        factory-method="getInstance" />

    <bean id="config" class="com.sinarotech.m2m.util.Configuration"
        factory-method="getInstance" />

    <bean id="tipsFactory"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.web.util.TipsFactory">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="tips.drl" />
        <property name="config" ref="config" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="affiliateHandlerFactory"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.affiliate.AffiliateHandlerFactory"
        factory-method="getInstance" />

    <bean id="twitterHandler"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.twitter.AtomTwitterHandler" />

    <bean id="bankManager"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.service.BankManager"
        factory-method="getInstance" />

    <bean id="exchangeManager"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.web.util.ExchangeManager">
        <constructor-arg value="exchange.properties" />
        <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
        <property name="contextCache" ref="contextCache" />
    </bean>
 <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/> 
    <bean id="supportProvider"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.support.HelpspotSupportProvider" />



<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>
</beans>
</beans>
```

Spring Security with oauth

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"    
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd       
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- Stateless RESTful services use BASIC authentication -->
    <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config='true' create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token"/>
        <security:http-basic/>
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>  
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>  
    </security:http>
    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="client-details-service" token-services-ref="tokenServices">  
        <oauth:authorization-code />  
        <oauth:implicit />  
        <oauth:refresh-token />  
        <oauth:client-credentials />  
  <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationOauthManager"/>   
    </oauth:authorization-server> 
    <beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"  
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">  
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>  
    </beans:bean> 

    <beans:bean id="jdbcDaoImpl" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="enableGroups" value="true" />
         <beans:property name="enableAuthorities" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean> 

    <!-- Oauth Client Verification Configuration -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="client-details-service">


        <!-- Web Application clients -->
        <oauth:client
                client-id="NofaAdmin"
                secret="655f523128212d6e70634446224c2a48"
                authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token,authorization_code"

                access-token-validity="5184000"
                refresh-token-validity="5184000"
                />
</oauth:client-details-service>



    <beans:bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </beans:bean>



    <beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>  
    <!-- Token Generation -->
    <beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">  
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>  
        <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>  
        <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="client-details-service"/>  
    </beans:bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationOauthManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
<!--    Storing Generated Tokens In Database
 -->     <!-- <beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
       <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>  -->
        <beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"/>  

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

    <!-- Security JDBC Authentication Manager -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <security:authentication-provider>
           <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
          "select email,password,1 from USER where email=?" 

            authorities-by-username-query=
            "select * from ROLE r INNER JOIN (select * from USER u INNER JOIN ROLE_USER ru on u.ID=ru.USER_ID where u.email=? limit 1) roleobj on roleobj.ROLE_ID=r.ID"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
<!-- <security:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>  
    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">  
    <beans:property name="decisionVoters">   
        <beans:list>  
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250Voter"/>  
        </beans:list>  
    </beans:property>  
</beans:bean>  -->
```

Exception I got is:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[remember.localhost].[/].[spring]] Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception: error="invalid_grant", error_description="Bad credentials"
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.getOAuth2Authentication(ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.java:74) [:]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.getAccessToken(AbstractTokenGranter.java:70) [:]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.grant(AbstractTokenGranter.java:65) [:]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.CompositeTokenGranter.grant(CompositeTokenGranter.java:38) [:]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(TokenEndpoint.java:115) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_45]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.opensymphony.webwork.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:189) [:2.2.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_45]
```

Answer (score 4):

Bad credentials means you are supplying wrong password. I guess you supplied plain password instead of encrypted password?

Comment: the "bad credentials" error is accompanied with an "invalid_grant" error. So it should not be that.

Comment: Your comment gave me a hint, I realized that, in the UserDetailsService implementation, I had returned UserDetails without encoding the password. In my project I have used a password encoder. One up for the hint.